# Find recurrence relation for a sum

Tags: recursion

Let's say I want to find a recursive equation for an exponentially weighted moving average

```
EV[t_]:=(a-1)/(a^t-1)*Sum[a^(t-i)*x[i],{i,1,t}]
```

I can do that manually to come up with an equation

```
EVR[t_]:=(a-1)/(a^t-1)*x[t]+(a^t-a)/(a^t-1)*EVR[t-1]
EVR[1]=x[1]
```

We can check whether the manually derived equation is correct via

```
Table[(EV[i]==EVR[i])//FullSimplify,{i,2,10}]
```

which gives

```
{True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True}
```

In Mathematica, how would I find the recursive equation for `EVR[t]` assuming that the equation for `EV[t]` is given?

Also, the exponentially weighted moving average is just a minimal example. The actual sums are more complicated.

Comment: EVR is not recursive at all. It refers to EV and not to itself.

Comment: I have defined `EVR` so that the check in the next line is shorter. Otherwise, I would have had to write `Table[(EV[t]==(a-1)/(a^t-1)*x[t]+(a^t-a)/(a^t-1)*EV[t-1])//FullSimplify,{t,2,10}]`. But I will change this to make it clearer.

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken, but I feel you missed the point. In a recurrence equation you relate a given element of a sequence to one or more earlier or later elements of the same sequence. In this case, your second definition then should have EV[t_] as the left-hand side, which would be problematic as you haven't specified a stopping criterion.

Comment: Anyway, most folks want to go the other way: they have a recursive function and need to have a closed form solution. That can be done with `RSolve`.  Not sure if it is possible to go the other way.

Comment: I made some changes to my post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible approach. Would need some work to generalize to higher degree though.

```
recursiveSum[fac_.*Sum[term_*x_[i_], {i_, n_}]] :=
 Module[
  {topterm, c, genterm, soln},
  topterm = fac*term*x[i] /. i -> n;
  genterm = Table[fac*term /. n -> nn, {nn, n - 1, n}];
  soln = c /. First[Solve[{c, 1}.genterm == 0, c]];
  topterm + Together[soln]*Sum[term*x[i], {i, n - 1}]
  ]
```

That example:

```
recursiveSum[(a - 1)/(a^t - 1)*Sum[a^(t - i)*x[i], {i, t}]]

(* Out[92]= -(((-a + a^t)*Sum[a^(-i + t)*x[i], {i, -1 + t}])/(-1 + 
      a^t)) + ((-1 + a)*x[t])/(-1 + a^t) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a general solution but one that does hint at it. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073530/get-mathematica-to-simplify-expression-with-another-equation)

I have tried the following for `t=5`:

```
ElEq = Eliminate[{A == EV[5], EV[4]==B}, Table[x[i],{i, 1, 4}]]
Flatten[Collect[Solve[ElEq,A], {B,x[5]}]]
```

This gives

```
{A->(B (a+a^2+a^3+a^4))/(1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4)+x[5]/(1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4)}
```

Now one can see that the factor for `B` goes like

```
Sum[a^i,{i,1,t-1}]/Sum[a^i,{i,0,t-1}]
```

This can be simplified with `FullSimplify` to give

```
(a^t-a)/(a^t-1)
```

which is the correct factor for `EVR[t-1]`.
The same can be done for `x[t]`, which also gives the correct factor

```
1/Sum[a^i,{i,0,t-1}]
```

or simplified

```
(a-1)/(a^t-1)
```

---

An alternative solution:

```
CoefficientRules[Flatten[Solve[ElEq, A][[1,2]], {B, x[5]}]//FullSimplify
```

This gives

```
{{1,0}->1-1/(1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4),
 {0,1}->1/(1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4)}
```

From there it would nice if one could use `FindSequenceFunction` on the factors for `B` and `x[5]` but the expressions seem to be to complicated.

Comment: I do not accept my post as an answer yet because I would rather like to see a general solution. So if anyone has a general solution, I am happy to accept it.